# How can I evaluate this sum?

Tags: calculus

How can I evaluate this sum ?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}n^p$$

I know when $p\in \Bbb N$ but when $p\in\Bbb R$ what do I do ?

please help and thanks for all

Comment: Do you mean "find a closed formula" or actually "evaluate". For the first one, I think it's hard. For the second one, just compute...

Comment: actually "evaluate but if it hard 
ok  closed formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p \in \mathbb{N}$, you have the [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), i.e.,
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^p = \dfrac1{p+1} \sum_{j=0}^p (-1)^j \dbinom{p+1}j B_j m^{p+1-j}$$
where $B_j$ are the Bernoulli numbers, with $B_1 = - \dfrac12$. If $p \not\in \mathbb{N}$, we can still obtain the asymptotic behavior as
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^p \sim \begin{cases}\dfrac{m^{p+1}}{p+1} & \text{ if } p \neq -1\\ \log(m) + \gamma & \text{ if } p =-1\end{cases}$$